# Tweenengine Timeline not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to shake an object using java universal tween engine.

Below is the code.
but only the first animation runs. Could anybody help me with this?

```
float time = 0.5f;
        float shakeAngle = 10;
        Timeline.createSequence()
        .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*2.0f))
        .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*-1.0f))
        .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*0.0f))
        .start(TweenManagerHelper.sharedInstance().manager);
```

Comment: maybe you're not passing the right delta time update to the tween manager. What's going on with the time variable above? It's not used?

Comment: is this solved? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Tween Engine, but looking around I found and example of its usage here:

[java-universal-tween-engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/source/browse/tween-engine-api/src/aurelienribon/tweenengine/Timeline.java?r=c32fd360d0ce713e69c8fe78d945cb3deb1f1a4a&spec=svna906749e4c2277648edbe3efd98e50b3b18d786d)

Here is the relative part that can be useful to you:

```
float time = 0.5f;
float shakeAngle = 10;
Timeline.createSequence()
    .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*2.0f).ease(Quad.INOUT))
    .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*-1.0f).ease(Quad.INOUT))
    .push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*0.0f).ease(Quad.INOUT))
    .start(TweenManagerHelper.sharedInstance().manager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the .beginSequence() and end() functions.
.beginSequence() right after the CreateSequence() and end() after your last animation in the timeline

```
float time = 0.5f;
float shakeAngle = 10;
Timeline.createSequence()
.beginSequence()
.push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*2.0f))
.push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*-1.0f))
.push(Tween.to(this, TWEEN_ROTATION, 0.5f).target(shakeAngle*0.0f))
.end()
.start(TweenManagerHelper.sharedInstance().manager);
```